# Why is infinite inputting of a variable happening in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

```
num = int(input())
evenCounter = 0
while num != 0:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evenCounter += 1

print(evenCounter)
```

Maybe this is sort of silly question, but I really can't figure out why does inifite input of the variable happen here. The console just keep asking me to write in a number for some reason.

Comment: because you are only asking for `num` once outside of the loop. you might want to put the input inside the loop. Your program asks for input once, and unless you input 0 it will hang in an infinite loop, since num will never be modified again, so the condition to exit the loop will never be met.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes, the input for the `num` variable is outside the loop, not inside of it, so there should be no repeated asking for entering variable, am I wrong?

Comment: the code you posted doesn't repeatedly ask the user for input, it only asks once, then hangs.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki but I'm able to type in a new number, and another new number, and another, etc.

Comment: you type new numbers into terminal but nothing happens with them, they're just shown in terminal but they aren't touched by your program. your program meanwhile are just stuck in a while loop

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I'm running it from Pycharm. I also tried to run it here [https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler], and it asks me to type in the number over and over again

Comment: Check @DmitriyNeledva answer. Try what is suggested there and accept the answer if it explains your problem. Citing Month Python: "It's not running! 'It's passed on! This program is no more! It has ceased to be! it has expired and gone to meet it's maker! it's metabolic processes are now history! This is an ex-program.

Comment: You should put a prompt in the `input()` call so you can see when it's asking for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you get it wrong, it asks user input just once, and then it's stuck in a while loop, and you think that it's asking user anther input. To check it just add some text in `input('add some text here: ' )` and you'll see that input is called just once.